# How to retweets username in mgttwitter in iphone app

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

i integrated twitter in iphone app. i am able to fetch data from twiiter but I have to know screenName of those user who retweets any post. suppose I am fetching a post from my Wall and I am seeing that post has retweets by 2 times. I want to know username of last retweets person?

If any idea please know me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ajay : i suggest to take a look at this One - has all twitter features integrated .

https://github.com/luciuskwok/HelTweetica

Hope this helps!